# HTML, ASP - Passing Drop Down List Values To Another Page Using Session

Tags: html, asp.net

I would like to add sessions where I can pass the selected values from the drop down lists to a new page via url. I have done this method by using JavaScript but I would like to use session instead.

Need help on this one.

P.S : This involves two drop down list which can pass the selected values to multiple pages.

```html
<h4>Choose a Product &nbsp: </h4>

<select id="product"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="PCR">
 <option value = "ELM">ELM</option>
 <option value = "EPP">EPP</option>
 <option value = "ELP">ELP</option>
 <option value = "EPP">EPP</option>
 </optgroup>
 </select>
<br><br><br>

<h4>Choose a Profile &nbsp: </h4>

<select id="profile"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
  
 <optgroup label="TEST PROFILES">
 <option value = "Full">FULL</option>
 <option value = "QRC">QRC</option>
 <option value = "Cold">COLD</option>
 </optgroup>
 </select>
<br><br>

<div class="rfloat">
  <input type="submit" id="btngo" value="Go" class="button button2" />
</div>
```

Comment: webforms or mvc?

Comment: Hi @KanisXXX. Thanks for the feedback. It's a web form.

Comment: @EdSF Thanks for the feedback. It is not the same, I need to do it from a drop down list and to direct to multiple pages as well.

Comment: @xerxes39 It is at the base level. You're asking how to (properly) use `Session` so understanding what it is is where you should _start_

Comment: @EdSF I guess I know how to session a value from one page to another but I do not know how to it from a drop down list itself. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using normal HTML controls so you have to convert your HTML controls into asp.net controls, your `select` control will be converted into `asp:DropDownList` control.

Second you can set sessions in many ways. However for example I am setting it on dropdown's `OnSelectedIndexChanged` so the **aspx** code will look like this

```
    <h4>Choose a Product &nbsp: </h4>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="product" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="product_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="NONE">NONE</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="ELM">ELM</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="EPP">EPP</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="ELP">ELP</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="EPP">EPP</asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList>

            <h4>Choose a Profile &nbsp: </h4>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="profile" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="profile_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="NONE">NONE</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Full">FULL</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="QRC">QRC</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Cold">COLD</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <div class="rfloat">
                <input type="submit" id="btngo" value="Go" class="button button2" />
            </div>
        </div>`
```

And your code behind code looks like this.

```
        protected void product_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Product"] = product.SelectedItem.Text;
        }

        protected void profile_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Product"] = profile.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I am unable to run the code. The `asp:ListItem` codes doesn't seem to work  for me. And do I need to write any codes on the new page?

Comment: @xerxes39 are you working on HTML page or aspx page?

Comment: I am working on an asp page.